# Can we differentiate Physical Sim and Esim info. received by CTCarrier

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am currently trying to get the carrier info. from device. If I call -

```
 CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkinfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
 NSDictionary *carriers = networkinfo.serviceSubscriberCellularProviders;
 CTCarrier *carrInfo;
 for(id key in carriers.allKeys){
 carrInfo = carriers[key];
 NSLog("%@", carrInfo);
 }
```

This gives output -

```
Carrier [name: Airtel, MCC: 208, MNC: 15, ISO Country Code: IN Allows VOIP: YES]
Carrier [name: Jio, MCC: 210, MNC: 20, ISO Country Code: IN Allows VOIP: YES]
```

But which is physical sim and which is E-sim, I am not able to differentiate.
Also. I read about this that this output can be switched at runtime, not fixed.
So how will I be able to differentiate which one is e-sim and which one is physical sim.

Comment: I've tried ur code , i am getting country code as 6526 numbers not US Or IN , how did u manage to get country code as string instead of numbers ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no public API or property exposed by Apple to differentiate between pSIM and eSIM programmatically.

EID is something that uniquely identifies the eSIM profile downloaded in the device. Again, Apple does not allow to read this Settings.